# Why am I getting "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values."

Tags: arrays, matlab

Can anyone find where my code is throwing an error for this function? alpha_p and width are both arrays where all numbers are positive.

```
gain2 = (alpha_p.'./(1-exp(-alpha_p.'.*width.'))).*((((2.*(exp((-2.*alpha_.*(1-k)-alpha_p.').*width.'))-1))./(-2.*alpha_.*(1-k)-alpha_p.'))-(((exp(-2.*alpha_.*(1-k).*width')-k)./(exp(-alpha_(1-k).*width.')-k)).*((1-exp((-alpha_.*(1-k)-alpha_p.').*width.'))./(alpha_.*(1-k)+alpha_p.'))));
```

Comment: You may want to break up the code/function into smaller pieces. This makes it easier to handle, more readable, and helps you when debugging.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal and reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error propagates from the section indicated by the box in the below image. May be caused by a missing operator between `-alpha_` and `(1-k)`. Assuming of course that the variable `alpha_` is a constant/scalar and not another array.

[image: Error Image]

Extension:
Debugged using find functionality on each variable and looking for any variable that does not follow valid indexing.

Comment: This was the fix! Probably seemed like a silly question but sometimes you need a second set of eyes. Thanks a bunch!